# As the symfony add html in the widget

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I make a widget for entering a phone number, extends from `sfWidgetFormInputText`. The goal is to add `<span>+7<span>`.

How to implement it?

Comment: `+7` as default text of the widget or add `+7` to the entered value ?

Comment: "+7" - just span. 


<span>+7</span>
<input type="text" name="profile" value="" id="profile_phone">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your widget class:

```
class MyWidgetFormInputPhoneNumber extends sfWidgetFormInputText 
{

    public function render($name, $value = null, $attributes = array(), $errors = array())
    {
        return '<span>+7</span> '.parent::render($name, $value, $attributes, $errors);
    }
}
```